# Accessing columns when looping over record composed of result of 2 subqueries

Tags: postgresql

I have a code block in which I am looping over a record that contains two joined subqueries that contain equally named columns in different tables.

Now I seem to be able to access sq1 and sq2 in the record, but not the contents and I always get "could not identify column 'c1' in record data type", even if I add explicit aliases to the columns:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT sq1, sq2
        FROM (SELECT t1.someColumn as c1, t2.someColumn as c2, ... FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ...) sq1
        JOIN (SELECT t1.someColumn as c1, t2.someColumn as c2, ... FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ...) sq2
        ON (sq1.joinColumn1 = sq2.joinColumn2 AND sq1.joinColumn2 = sq2.joinColumn1)
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO Table3 (column1, column2)
        VALUES ((r.sq1).c1, (r.sq2).c1);
               --^ error occurs here
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

I am looking for a way to access the records similar to the following way:

```
r.sq1.t1.someColumn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For access to the 3 level in your variable you must cast it as named record type. It might be table or type:

For type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (c1 int4, c2 int4, joinColumn1 int4);
```

For table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_type (c1 int4, c2 int4, joinColumn1 int4);
```

And after that you can do something like this:

```
DO $$

DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT (sq1.*)::my_type AS sq1, (sq2.*)::my_type AS sq2
        FROM (SELECT 10 as c1, 11 as c2, 1 as joinColumn1) sq1
        JOIN (SELECT 20 as c1, 21 as c2, 1 as joinColumn2) sq2
        ON (sq1.joinColumn1 = sq2.joinColumn2)
    LOOP
          RAISE NOTICE '%', r;
          RAISE NOTICE '%', r.sq1;
          RAISE NOTICE '% %', (r.sq1).c1, (r.sq2).c1;
          INSERT INTO Table3 (column1, column2)
          VALUES ((r.sq1).c1, (r.sq2).c1);
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I was looking for, thanks! That way I even can get rid of the aliases for c1 and c2.